# Python algorithm to search nested lists to check if a list already exists

Tags: python, algorithm, list, search, nested

I am having some trouble trying to figure out a simple algorithm in Python to check if a new list already exists in a list before I add the new list if that makes sense? For example:

```
List 1 = [[P1, 3, P2, 2], [P3, 3, P4, 2], [P5, 1, P6, 3]]
List 2 = [P1, 3, P2, 2]
```

Basically what I'm wanting to do is check whether or not "List 2" already exists in "List 1" before I actually add it to the list. I realize this is probably quite simple to achieve however, I am fairly new to programming and am having some trouble working out how to do this.

I also wanted to ask how I would for example, check the lists to see if a value is greater than 3? like for example if I have the list:

```
List 1 = [[P1, 3, P2, 2], [P3, 4, P4, 2]]
```

I realize "How do I do this" questions aren't appropriate for Stack Overflow however, I have looked through the internet for answers and am still struggling so any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for existence, just use `in`:

```
List1 = [['P1', 3, 'P2', 2], ['P3', 3, 'P4', 2], ['P5', 1, 'P6', 3]]
List2 = ['P1', 3, 'P2', 2]
if List2 in List1:
   do_something()
```

To find lists that have a second value greater than or equal to 3:

```
List1 = [['P1', 3, 'P2', 2], ['P3', 3, 'P4', 2], ['P5', 1, 'P6', 3]]
new_list = [i for i in List1 if i[1] >= 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l1 = [['P1', 3, 'P2', 2], ['P3', 3, 'P4', 2], ['P5', 1, 'P6', 3]]
l2 = ['P1', 3, 'P2', 2]

if l2 not in l1:
    l1.append(l2)
```

Adds `l2` to `l1` if it's not present in `l1`. In this case, as `l2` is present in `l1`, no change.

Second part of your question: to check if item in list is greater than 3

```
l1 = [['P1', 3, 'P2', 2], ['P3', 4, 'P4', 2], ['P5', 1, 'P6', 3]]

for i in l1:
    for j in i:
        if type(j) is int:
            if j > 3:
                print("Greater than 3")
```